# Wie sagt man "To drum your fingers against something" auf Deutsch?

Tags: expression

Ich weiß nicht wie das ausdrücken kann. Ich hatte es versucht im Internet zu finden, aber es war ne Niete. Ich wollte sagen, "I drummed my fingers on my keyboard to get random letters". Aber ich weiß nicht... gibt es nicht auf Deutsch solche Ausdrücke?

Comment: Wieweit bist Du denn gekommen, was macht konkret Schwierigkeiten?

Comment: "Die Finger auf etwas trommeln :D" Ich weiß nicht ob das richtig ist, aber ich glaube nicht...

Comment: Ich weiß nicht wie man in Deutschland das ausdrücken würde... und ich konnte nix finden in mein Wörterbuch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich würde es folgendermaßen sagen.

Wenn es etwas wild sein soll: `hämmern`. Da kommt eher die Bedeutung von *to hack* durch. „Er hämmerte zehn Sekunden lang auf der Tastatur herum, um zufällige Buchstabenkombinationen zu erhalten.“

Man könnte `eingeben` verwenden: „Er gab wahllos Zeichen ein, bis er mit dem Buchstabensalat zufrieden war.“

Wenn es eher ruhig klingen soll: `tippen / drücken`. Bei tippen habe ich noch den Eindruck, dass ein Tippfähiger versucht, Entropie zu erzeugen. Bei drücken denke ich eher an ein kleines Kind, welches auf Mamas Rechner herumpatscht. „Er tippte / drückte zufällige Buchstaben und Zahlen, bis das Textfeld voll war.“

`Trommeln`, wie in den anderen Antworten beschrieben, geht natürlich auch.

Mir fallen viele Synonyme für `tippen` ein: Es gäbe da noch `in die Tasten hauen` und `klampfen`, `kloppen`, `dreschen` (Imperfekt: `drosch`) und `schlagen`, aber das Gefühl, das du suchst, wird eher durch den Zusammenhang vermittelt. Eine Konstruktion wie „auf der Tastatur herum+*Verb*“ oder ein dazu passendes Adjektiv (wahllos, zufällig etc.) sind genauso wichtig wie das Verb selbst, weil sie den Kontext gut zur Geltung bringen.

Answer (score 0):

> "I drummed my fingers on my keyboard to get random letters."

Ich würde schreiben:

```
Ich trommelte mit meinen Fingern auf die Tastatur, 
um Zufallsbuchstaben zu erzeugen (bekommen).
```

"Bekommen" ist möglich und näher am "get" – je nach Kontext passt es auch besser, evtl. sogar "kriegen".

Allerdings trommeln wir nicht **die** Tastatur, sondern **auf der** Tastatur. Bei richtigen Schlaginstrumenten (Basstrommel, Conga, …) könnte man auch sagen "Ich trommle die Bongos"; aber da eine Tastatur üblicherweise nicht zum Trommeln benutzt wird, kann man das schlecht sagen.

Answer (score 0):

Am nächsten käme meinem Empfinden nach:

Mit den Fingern gegen etwas trommeln.

Beispielsweise: Er trommelte mit den Fingern gegen die Fensterscheibe.